# accessing vue-model properties using ${}

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a tiny snippet that works correctly when I use `:src="labels[index]"`, but my code is growing and I will need to use `${app.labels[index]}`. I can do just `${app.labels}`, but once I add the `[index]` part, it breaks. Can someone tell me how to add that inside the brackets?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    images: [],
        labels: [],
          form: {
            dir: "",
            fileItems: [] // An array containing objects of type: {id: number, file: File, dataUrl: [base64 encoded file string], caption: string'}
          },
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
      <div class="image-wrap"><img style="max-height: 430px;" :src="${app.labels[index]}" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue when you use `:` in a prop you are basically telling Vue

> Please, interpret this expression side as javascript

An example:

```
<super-aweosme-component :a="1 + 1" />
```

Will result in the prop `a` being `2` (because it was interpreted as javasript).

When you don't use `:` in a component prop you are telling Vue

> Please, interpret this as plain text

An example

```
<super-aweosme-component a="1 + 1" />
```

Will result in the prop `a` being literally `1 + 1` (string). So you can change `:src="${images.labels[index]}"` to just `:src="images.labels[index]"` (of course, apply the changes mentioned above)

## Adition

You have `app.labels[index]`. `app` doesn't exist in the template context. You have in that context `images`, `labels` and `form` (of course, there are attributes in that context but not important for this part)

Comment: already had tried it with without the {} of course. It needs it and app as well...i am using some vanilla js outside of vue.

Comment: just need someone to tell me how to add the [index] while use the ${}

Comment: if you truly want to use `${}` (which is absolutely not necessary here - please, re-read the answer so you can understand fully what you are doing) you can do `:src="\`${app.labels[index]}\`"`